# I keep receiving this error when trying to enable the execution of powershell scripts

Tags: powershell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key     'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied.
At line:1 char:20
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy <<<<  Unrestricted
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAcce 
ssException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :    System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C 
ommands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

Is there any way to bypass this? Or at least run my powershell code? Please help!

Comment: Right-click on the Powershell icon that you are starting Powershell with and select Run as Administrator, and then set the execution policy.

Comment: You have to be running as an administrator in order to enable execution of scripts. Are you running as admin?

Comment: no I am not, and I can't, since the computer i am working on is used widely.

Comment: Then you need to get an admin on the system to allow it (which sounds like it might not be possible). What execution policy are you trying to set?

Comment: According to the post, Unrestricted.

Comment: I am also ok with the "remotesigned" option

Comment: If you need to run scripts for a legitimate purpose, you need to take this up with the group that administers these PCs.  They aren't allowing scripts to be run for a number of reasons, as it can provide a means for malware to damage the system and propagate to other systems, among other things.

Comment: @TonyHinkle If your goal is to prevent scripts from runing, I wouldn't call ExectionPolicy [a security measure](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/).  It's a way to identify who signed the script and when and to detect unauthorized modifications to the file (which they shouldn't be able to make in the first place) but as a security measure it's moderately less secure than a paper bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following,

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .runme.ps1
```

and run this in a cmd prompt

or copy and paste the whole script in a PS Console